# React Resize Image Width px Based on Bootstrap Column

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, react-bootstrap

I'm using the `react-image-mapper` library, and the `ImageMapper` component accepts a prop called `width` which is the image width in px. I have used the `react-bootstrap` layout for my app, dividing it into three columns. The third column has the `ImageMapper`:

```
  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col md={5} />
        <Col md={2} />
        <Col md={5}> 
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <ImageMapper
              id="football-field"
              src={footballField}
              alt="football-field"
              width={resizeWidth()}
              map={MAP}
            />
          </div>
      </Row>
    </>);
```

I need to write `resizeWidth` so that it returns the width of the column in pixels. Is there a way to do this, or a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good library to access the width of the column: [react-use-measure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-measure)